# Make Div Draggable using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make my div tag with id "drag_me" to be draggable up to the length of 300px from left and 460px from top, only using CSS.

I also want to make it resizable. Again same condition as above i.e. no Javascript or jquery.

What's the solution for this?

Comment: Since it is necessary to know the starting and ending mouse coordinates, it is impossible without a line of Javascript. You either must accept JS or quit looking for a solution.

Comment: Btw, you can make a `div` "draggable" without JS, but you cannot "drag" it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is the best you can do without JavaScript:

```css
[draggable=true] {
  cursor: move;
}

.resizable {
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 460px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="resizable"></div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/exeheb/1/edit)**

- [`draggable` attribute on HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)
- [CSS `resize` property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: I wish dragging in that demo would work in Firefox or Chrome... that'd be really nice.

Comment: In July of 2018, this demo does not work. Please consider updating, if you have a modern technique that works.

Comment: Draggable function does not work, it only allows to resize

Comment: The demo does work on Chrome. It allows the user to drag the `div`. There's nowhere to drop it but it can be dragged from the original location.

Answer (score 20):

You can take a look at HTML 5, but I don't think you can restrict the area within you can drag it, just the destination:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

And if you don't mind using some great library, I would encourage you to try [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula).

Comment: I have already checked it but they are using javascript code. I don't want any javascript script at all for my project...

Comment: I have google for this a lot and come up with conclusion that its not possible with only CSS, I have to use javascript.             The solution you have given is the one and here is the another solution i have got                                                 http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zdsty

Comment: I would recommend you to use JavaScript or any of its libraries.

Answer (score 17):

Only using css techniques this does not seem possible to me. But you could use jqueryui [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/):

```javascript
$('#drag_me').draggable();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dominik. I know that using draggable() function of jqueryui its possible but i don't want to use jquery or javascript. Please direct me if any one have any idea

Answer (score 14):

I found [this from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) is really helpful:

```js
// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Draggable DIV -->
<div id="mydiv">
  <!-- Include a header DIV with the same name as the draggable DIV, followed by "header" -->
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

I hope you can use it to!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreicated. Was stumped for a bit but realised that I needed to call the javascript after defining the <div>.

Answer (score 10):

CSS is designed to describe the presentation of documents. It has a few features for changing that presentation in reaction to user interaction (primarily `:hover` for indicating that you are now pointing at something interactive).

Making something draggable isn't a simple matter of presentation. It is firmly in the territory of interactivity logic, which is handled by JavaScript.

What you want is not achievable.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it now by using the CSS property `-webkit-user-drag`:

```css
#drag_me {
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" id="drag_me">
  Your draggable content here
</div>
```

This property is only supported by webkit browsers, such as Safari or Chrome, but it is a nice approach to get it working using only CSS.

The HTML5 `draggable` attribute is only set to ensure dragging works for other browsers.

You can find more information here: http://help.dottoro.com/lcbixvwm.php

Answer (score 6):

**Draggable and resizable dialog in pure CSS is posible.**

Dialog parameters

- Left: 40px ... 300px
- Top: 40px ... 460px
- Width: 150px ... 300px
- Height: 100px ... 200px

Relocation principle: The dialog is located in the second row and second column of the table. In the first column and the first row of the table there is another div with the possibility of resizing. The second cell of the table is moved by resizing the first cell.

The resizer is moved over the second cell using the negative margin of the first cell and cut out using clip-path.

The default resizer icon is overlaid with an image.

I sorry for my English.

```css
:root {
--resizer-size:18px;
--border-size:3px;
}
.area {
position:relative;
background-color:white;
width:700px;
height:700px;
font-size:14px;
line-height:30px
}
.tbl {
position:absolute;
border-collapse:collapse;
pointer-events:none
}
.tbl TD {
padding:0
}
.mover {
position:relative;
background-color:yellow;
top:0;
left:0;
width:200px; /*Default left*/
height:100px; /*Default top*/
resize:both;
overflow:auto;
margin-bottom:calc(var(--border-size)*-1 - var(--resizer-size));
margin-right:calc(var(--border-size)*-1 - var(--resizer-size));
z-index: 1;
pointer-events:all;
clip-path: polygon(calc(100% - var(--resizer-size)) calc(100% - var(--resizer-size)), 100% calc(100% - var(--resizer-size)), 100% 100%, calc(100% - var(--resizer-size)) 100%);
min-width:40px;  /*4x Limits dialog position*/
max-width:300px;
min-height:40px;
max-height:460px
}
.moverIco {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
width:var(--resizer-size);
height:var(--resizer-size);
background:black;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="white" \
  d="M13,11H18L16.5,9.5L17.92,8.08L21.84,12L17.92,15.92L16.5,14.5L18,13H13V18L14.5,16.5L15.92,17.92L12,21.84L8.08,17.92L9.5,16.5\
  L11,18V13H6L7.5,14.5L6.08,15.92L2.16,12L6.08,8.08L7.5,9.5L6,11H11V6L9.5,7.5L8.08,6.08L12,2.16L15.92,6.08L14.5,7.5L13,6V11Z" /></svg>')
}
.dialog {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:200px; /*Default width*/
height:120px; /*Default height*/
border:var(--border-size) solid green;
background-color:#EEE;
resize:both;
overflow:auto;
pointer-events:all;
text-align:center;
min-width:150px; /*4x Limits dialog size*/
max-width:300px;
min-height:100px;
max-height:200px
}
.dialog .head {
background:green;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:calc(var(--border-size) + var(--resizer-size));;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
height:calc(var(--border-size) + var(--resizer-size));;
line-height:var(--resizer-size);
text-align:left
}
```

```html
<DIV class=area>
  <TABLE class=tbl>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <DIV class=mover>
          <DIV class=moverIco></DIV>
        </DIV>
      </TD>
      <TD></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD>
        <DIV class=dialog>
          <DIV class=head>Dialog</DIV><BR>Sure?<BR><BUTTON>Yes</BUTTON> <BUTTON>No</BUTTON>
        </DIV>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.
Nunc dapibus tortor vel mi dapibus sollicitudin. Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet, feugiat eu, orci. Nam quis nulla.
Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Curabitur sagittis hendrerit ante. Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate,
erat libero tristique tellus, nec bibendum odio risus sit amet ante. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum tincidunt diam. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.
Nunc dapibus tortor vel mi dapibus sollicitudin. Fusce dui leo, imperdiet in, aliquam sit amet, feugiat eu, orci. Nam quis nulla.
Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Curabitur sagittis hendrerit ante. Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate,
erat libero tristique tellus, nec bibendum odio risus sit amet ante. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit.
</DIV>
```

Comment: Wow, this is cool. Very clever

Comment: This is a really fun solution! Maybe not ideal for real world use but a great proof of concept.

Answer (score 2):

After going down the rabbit-hole of trying to do this myself by copy-pasting various code-snippets from Stack Overflow, I would highly recommend just using the [InteractJS library](https://interactjs.io), which allows you to create a draggable and resizable div (somewhat) easily.

Answer (score 1):

Draggable div `not possible only with CSS`, if you want draggable div you must need to use javascript.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and found that it was honestly just better to use jquery. I'm new to web development but the library is super small and this take is completed with just one function instead of that whole block in the w3schools answer. if your project allows it (like mine ended up) use this solution

```
$(function(){
    $("#item").dragable()
});
```

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking. Besides, there is another almost identical answer to which the OP replied that this is not what he was asking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#dialog').draggable({ handle: "#tblOverlay" , scroll: false });

    // Pop up Window 
          <div id="dialog">
                        <table  id="tblOverlay">
                            <tr><td></td></tr>
                         <table>
           </div>
```

Options:

1. handle :  Avoids the sticky scroll bar issue. Sometimes your mouse pointer  will stick to the popup window while dragging.
2. scroll : Prevent popup window  to go beyond parent page or out of current
   screen.

Comment: The question asks us not to use JavaScript or jQuery.