# ion.rangeSlider: make it dragagble on mobile divices

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using ion.rangeSlider from [This repo](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider)
, and i want to know if there is a way of make it draggable on mobile divices, if yes how?

Comment: You might find [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526712/make-div-draggable-using-css) question on how to drag elements using HTML helpful.

Comment: This just changes the type of cursor to move if the draggale attribute is defined.