# How do I make a button draggable in html?

Tags: javascript, html, button, draggable

So I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        score = 0
        function hi(buttonID){
            score += 1
            document.getElementById("label123").innerHTML = score
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="hi(this)" id="Button123">
        <img src="button.png" alt="Button" width="100px" height="100px" draggable="true">
    </button>
    <label id="label123">Click it!</label>
    <h1> clicker.io </h1>
</html>
```

And I want to make the button (Button123) draggable.
This will make it so that the user can experience the ability to move the button anywhere they want on the screen.

Comment: first of all make your button in a div then follow the link [Make Div Draggable using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526712/make-div-draggable-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My old, laggy solution (min 4 FPS on firefox)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
function drag(e) {
  btn.style.left = `${e.pageX - 10}px`;
  btn.style.top = `${e.pageY - 10}px`;
}
btn.addEventListener("mousedown", () =>
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", drag)
);
btn.addEventListener("mouseup", () =>
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag)
);
```

```css
#btn {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

New solution using `transform: translate()` (min 40 FPS on firefox)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
function drag(e) {
  btn.style.transform = `translate(${e.pageX - 20}px, ${e.pageY - 20}px)`;
}
btn.addEventListener("mousedown", () =>
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", drag)
);
btn.addEventListener("mouseup", () =>
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag)
);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```